# Airflow: DAG marked successful, but task was not scheduled

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a slightly complex setup:
I run my Airflow (v1.10.13) pipelines in local time (setup on the VM's timezone). The following DAG was marked for the Monday run as successful, but the task within was never scheduled (thus having no logs whatsoever). I had some issues with the Airflow scheduler and usage of non-UTC timezones in the past, so I wonder, if that could be another reason?

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import timedelta
from somewhere import get_localized_yesterday
import prepered_tasks as t

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': get_localized_yesterday(),
    'email': [],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

# Schedule the DAG daily at 2 a.m.
dag = DAG(
    'descriptive_DAG_name',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='',
    schedule_interval='0 2 * * Mon-Fri',
    tags=['PROD']
)
single_task = t.task_partial(dag=dag)
single_task
```

The 'task_partial' is a task object embedded in a partial, so I only need to provide the dag for instantiation. This works as intended in other pipelines, which work properly.

I checked the usual suspects:

- The scheduler is running.
- The workers are running.
- The DAG is turned on in the UI.
- Other pipelines behave normally.
- No dependencies on previous runs.
- Start date lies well in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in airflow 1.10.13 and the release was yanked.

You should upgrade to 1.10.14.

See [the issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12659) and [the fix](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12663).

Quote from issue:

> After performing an upgrade to v1.10.13 we noticed that tasks in some of our DAGs were not be scheduled. After a bit of investigation we discovered that by commenting out 'depends_on_past': True the issue went away.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try an update then, but I can only do it next year. :)

Comment: Update: I did the update, and today morning it was the same situation as before: DAG marked as successful, task having no status.